# Beamer Headline - Insert Short Title with Auto Line Break

Tags: beamer, titles, headline

The following code prints title name into beamer headline using `\insertshorttitle`. The issue is,  for long titles, the line does not automatically break within the headline. Strange part is, line automatically breakes while using `\inserttitle`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tikzstyle{example-box} = [fill=yellow, align=left, rectangle, text width=\textwidth]

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [example-box] (box){
\insertshorttitle
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\title{A long title when inserted in the headline, using insertshorttitle does not break line. Whereas using inserttitle breaks the line. Specifying align=left in tikz block is not working either.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Insert the short title.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

While using \inserttitle:

[image]

While using \insertshorttitle:

[image: enter code here]

Does anybody know how to get autolinebreak inside headline while using `\insertshorttitle`? Thanks in advance

Comment: Without looking into the details of the short inserts in beamer, you could just use the internal macro `\beamer@shorttitle`, e.g., `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\insertrawshorttitle}{\beamer@shorttitle}
\makeatother` and then use `\insertrawshorttitle` instead.

Comment: Just use `\insertshorttitle[width=\textwidth]` or `\insertshorttitle[width=\textwidth, respectlinebreaks]` if you want to respect manual linebreaks in your title.

Comment: Did the above comments help solve your problem ?

Comment: @BambOo, yes, the above codes solved the issue.

Comment: @Ashok, ok, then I will vote to close this question as solved in the comments. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments